# slow moving, deleting files windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have a problem that when I connect to the internet (WiFi) moving and deleting files become very slow. Please note I'm also connected to my organisation mapped drive. I tried to solve the problem using many solutions but none worked. Any ideas?

When I disconnect from the internet moving, deleting files become fast.

Comment: These slow moving files are on the network drive? If so you should contact your system administrator for assistance

Comment: You can try deleting superfluous drives (NET USE T: /Delete).  Restart and see if that helps. Otherwise I think what you see is fairly normal.

Comment: @Ramhound I contacted them they could not figure out what is the problem exactly.

Comment: @John you mean I delete the mapped drive? will I lose any data?

Comment: Look in the list of drives (just NET USE) and see if there are connected drives you are not using. That is what I meant.  If files and apps are properly closed, deleting a mapped drive does not lose data.

Comment: @John Only 1 drive mapped. In addition to (MS OneDrive) for back ups.

Comment: Then it is an issue for your company to help you with.

Comment: @John Could OneDrive cause this issue?

Comment: It depends on your company VPN and setup. One Drive makes a local sync, so yes it can cause the issue (that is can or might cause).